# Why doesn't this generic extension method compile?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, extension-methods, covariance

The code is a little weird, so bear with me (keep in mind this scenario did come up in production code).

Say I've got this interface structure:

```
public interface IBase {  }
public interface IChild : IBase {  }

public interface IFoo<out T> where T : IBase {  }
```

With this extension method class built around the interfaces:

```
public static class FooExt
{
    public static void DoSomething<TFoo>(this TFoo foo)
        where TFoo : IFoo<IChild>
    {
        IFoo<IChild> bar = foo;

        //foo.DoSomethingElse();    // Doesn't compile -- why not?
        bar.DoSomethingElse();      // OK
        DoSomethingElse(foo);       // Also OK!
    }

    public static void DoSomethingElse(this IFoo<IBase> foo)
    {
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the commented-out line in `DoSomething` compile? The compiler is perfectly happy to let me assign `foo` to `bar`, which is of the same type as the generic constraint, and call the extension method on that instead. It's also no problem to call the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Can anyone confirm if this is a bug or expected behaviour?

Thanks!

Just for reference, here's the compile error (types abridged for legibility):

> 'TFoo' does not contain a definition for 'DoSomethingElse' and the best extension method overload 'DoSomethingElse(IFoo)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Which version of the .Net Framework are you using?

Comment: @Jackson: .NET 4 (otherwise I believe `out` wouldn't work)

Comment: @Jackson Pope, isn't that obvious with the `out` covariant generic definition of the `IFoo` interface?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `DoSomethingElse(foo)` and `DoSomethingElse(bar)`? The way you have it, foo and bar don't have any member functions

Comment: I believe it's because you are declaring the generic parameter as `out T` instead of `in T`. The IChild cannot be cast into `IFoo<IBase>`.

Comment: @Stargazer712 No, these are [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: @Stargazer: Aha! DoSomethingElse(foo) compiles (though why that would but not the other way, I don't know)! And yes, here `Foo` is absolutely useless, but it's just an example. In my real code, `Foo` has stuff in it.

Comment: @Tejs: I don't think so. The parameter has to be `out` otherwise I wouldn't be able to pass `IFoo<IChild>`s to `IFoo<IBase>` parameters (only the other way around).

Comment: @Anna Lear, ahh. Missed that :)

Comment: What's the reason for declaring `DoSomething<TFoo>(this TFoo foo) where TFoo : IFoo<IChild>` instead of `DoSomething(this IFoo<IChild> foo)` which is effectively equivalent?

Comment: @FacticiusVir: Good question! As you've pointed out, I don't really need the `TFoo` type here. In some of my real code, though, I have additional (interface) constraints on `IFoo`.

Answer (score 9):

Quoting the C# specification:

> 7.6.5.2 Extension method invocations
>
> In a method invocation (§7.5.5.1) of
>   one of the forms
>
> *expr . identifier ( )*
>
> *expr . identifier ( args )*
>
> *expr . identifier < typeargs > ( )*
>
> *expr . identifier < typeargs > ( args )*
>
> if the normal processing of the
>   invocation finds no applicable
>   methods, an attempt is made to process
>   the construct as an extension method
>   invocation. If *expr* or any of the args
>   has compile-time type *dynamic*,
>   extension methods will not apply.
>
> The objective is to find the best
>   type-name *C*, so that the corresponding
>   static method invocation can take
>   place:
>
> *C . identifier ( expr )*
>
> *C . identifier ( expr , args )*
>
> *C . identifier < typeargs > ( expr )*
>
> *C . identifier < typeargs > ( expr , args )*
>
> An extension method *Ci.Mj* is eligible
>   if:
>
> ·         *Ci* is a non-generic,
>   non-nested class
>
> ·         The name of *Mj* is identifier
>
> ·          *Mj* is accessible and
>   applicable when applied to the
>   arguments as a static method as shown
>   above
>
> ·         An implicit identity,
>   reference or boxing conversion exists
>   from *expr* to the type of the first
>   parameter of *Mj*.

Since `DoSomethingElse(foo)` compiles but `foo.DoSomethingElse()` doesn't, it seems like a compiler bug in overload resolution for extension methods: an implicit reference conversion exists from `foo` to `IFoo<IBase>`.

Comment: Interesting. Doesn't `DoSomethingElse(this IFoo<IBase> foo)` break the non-generic stipulation of Ci? The thing is, I can call that as an extension method on an `IFoo<IChild>`, just not on a generic type which happens to be `IFoo<IChild>` (specified with a generic constraint).

Comment: *Ci* refers to the class containing the extension method, `FooExt` in your sample code: this clauses basically says that you can't put an extension method in a generic or nested class. The only condition for the parameter is the last sentence, which passes the test.

Comment: Aha, thanks. That makes more sense. +1 for quoting the spec, though I still don't know why it isn't working ;-) I'm disinclined to believe it's a compiler bug -- they're way too rare. On the other hand, the behaviour I'm seeing doesn't seem to match the spec...

Answer (score 5):

Can you define *DoSomethingElse* in the *IFoo*?

```
public interface IFoo<out T> where T : IBase
{
    void DoSomethingElse();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Maybe you can then change the signature

```
public static void DoSomethingElse(this IFoo<IBase> foo)
=>
public static void DoSomethingElse<TFoo>(this TFoo foo) 
    where TFoo : IFoo<IChild>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no; not all `IFoo`s will have this method (in my real code I have additional generic constraints on the `TFoo` type parameter in the extension method)

Comment: +1 with the update. Add in the constraint `where TFoo : IFoo<IChild>` as on the other extension method, and I think you'll be in business.

Comment: I like what you propose in your update, but in my case it's quite painful to use with extension methods that already have (non-inferred) type parameters, since my real-life IFoo is also templated. I end up with calls like `thing.Method<FirstType, SecondType, IThirdType<FirstType, FourthType>>();` instead of `thing.Method<FirstType, SecondType>()`;

Comment: I can't shed any light on the problem without diving into the C# spec for a while, but at least for this example, I would simply change the signature of DoSomething like so:

`public static void DoSomething(this IFoo<IChild> foo) { ... }`

Does the generic parameter actually get you anything here?

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am actually using the generic out parameter -- I really do need to be able to call `DoSomethingElse` from `IFoo<IBase>`s as well.

Comment: @Mike: I completely misunderstood your comment the first time, sorry. I thought you were talking about the `IFoo<out T>` type parameter, but of course you meant the constraint on the method. I actually *am* using the generic parameter, so that I can specify additional constraints on `TFoo` besides the `IFoo<IChild>` one.

Answer (score 3):

I have found evidence that this is a "bug".

Although it is not necessary that a CLR language support all features available in MSIL, The fact is what you're trying to do is valid in MSIL.

If you were of a mind to dump the code into IL and make the DoSomething method look like this:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  DoSomething<(class TestLib.IFoo`1<class TestLib.IChild>) T>(!!T foo) cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       52 (0x34)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] class TestLib.IFoo`1<class TestLib.IChild> bar)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  box        !!T
  IL_0007:  call       void TestLib.Ext::DoSomethingElse(class TestLib.IFoo`1<class  TestLib.IBase>)
  IL_000c:  nop
  IL_000d:  ret
} // end of method Ext::DoSomething
```

you would discover that this compiles. And what does reflector resolve this as in C#?

```
public static void DoSomething<T>(this T foo) where T: IFoo<IChild>
{
    foo.DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: Fascinating, thanks! At least now we know it's supported by the CLR, if not the compiler :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why it doesn't compile, but is this an acceptable alternative?

```
public static void DoSomethingElse<T>(this IFoo<T> foo) where T : IBase
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but similar to oleksii's suggestion I'd rather not add more type parameters (since I have some already, and the type then couldn't be inferred, which is very annoying since I'm working with long typenames).

Answer (score 1):

Your piece of code

```
public static void DoSomethingElse(this IFoo<IBase> foo)
{
}
```

makes `DoSomethingElse` available only on `IFoo<IBase>` instances, what **foo** obviously isn't, since it's a `IFoo<IChild>`. The fact that `IChild` derives from `IBase` doesn't make `IFoo<IChild>` derive from `IFoo<IBase>`. So **foo** unfortunately cannot be considered as a kind of `IFoo<IBase>`, and `DoSomethingElse` therefore can't be invoked on it.

But this problem can easily be avoided if you slightly change your extension method this way :

```
public static void DoSomethingElse<T>(this IFoo<T> foo) where T : IBase
{
}
```

Now it compiles and all works fine.

The most interesting part is that `DoSomethingElse(foo);` compiles when called with a static method syntax but not with an extension method syntax. Obviously with a regular static method style call, generic covariance works well : the argument **foo** is typed as a `IFoo<IBase>` but can be assigned with a `IFoo<IChild>`, then the call is okay. But as an extension method, due to the way it is declared `DoSomethingElse` is made only available on instances formally typed as `IFoo<IBase>` , even if it would be compliant with `IFoo<IChild>`, so this syntax doesn't work on `IFoo<IChild>` instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's quite plausible, except that it doesn't explain why the extension method can be called on `bar` (which is still an `IFoo<IChild>`). It seems the implicit conversion from `IFoo<IChild>` to `IFoo<IBase>` *does* work even for extension method syntax, but not when it's a generic constraint specifying the type.

Comment: I missed this point. You are perfectly right. The difference in having **DoSomethingElse** available or not is not a matter of call style as I thought but of whether the instance is explicitely typed with a compliant type or with a generic type : the compiler is not smart enough to realize that the generic type is in fact a kind of `IFoo<IChild>` on which **DoSomethingElse** can apply.

Answer (score 0):

It does not compile for the reason that it is complaining about *'TFoo' does not contain a definition for 'DoSomethingElse'*

Your DoSomething is not defined to TFoo but for `IFoo<IBase>` and thus also for `IFoo<IChild>`.

Here are few changes I did. Have a look at what variants compile.

```
public interface IBase { }
public interface IChild : IBase { }

public interface IFoo<out T> where T : IBase { }

public static class FooExt
{
    public static void DoSomething<TFoo>(this TFoo foo)     where TFoo : IFoo<IChild>
    {
        IFoo<IChild> bar = foo;
        //Added by Ashwani 
        ((IFoo<IChild>)foo).DoSomethingElse();//Will Complie
        foo.DoSomethingElseTotally(); //Will Complie

        //foo.DoSomethingElse();    // Doesn't compile -- why not?
        bar.DoSomethingElse();      // OK
        DoSomethingElse(foo);       // Also OK!

    }

    public static void DoSomethingElse(this IFoo<IBase> foo)
    {
    }

    //Another method with is actually defined for <T>
    public static void DoSomethingElseTotally<T>(this T foo) 
    { 
    }
```

So hopefully it makes a bit more sense what compiles and what not and it is not a compiler bug.

HTH

Comment: I don't expect `TFoo` to have a `DoSomethingElse()` method, since `IFoo` doesn't have that method. The full error message is: 'TFoo' does not contain a definition for 'DoSomethingElse' *and the best extension method overload has some invalid arguments*. I'm expecting the compiler to use that extension method -- the compiler can resolve the call just fine when the constraint (and `DoSomethingElse`'s parameter) is changed to a regular, non-covariant interface (e.g. `ICloneable`).

Comment: Well as of now the complier does not do so. It can for non covariant interfaces as you said but I dont see a way for the compiler to do this in this case.

Comment: Right. Hence my question asking whether this is a bug or not :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that variance only works on reference types or identity conversions, from the spec (section 13.1.3.2):

```
A type T<A1, …, An> is variance-convertible to a type T<B1, …, Bn> if T is either an interface or a delegate type declared with the variant type parameters T<X1, …, Xn>, and for each variant type parameter Xi one of the following holds:
•         Xi is covariant and an implicit reference or identity conversion exists from Ai to Bi
•         Xi is contravariant and an implicit reference or identity conversion exists from Bi to Ai
•         Xi is invariant and an identity conversion exists from Ai to Bi
```

The compiler can't verify that `TFoo` isn't a struct that implements `IFoo<IChild>`, so it doesn't find the desired extension method.  Adding a `class` constraint to `DoSomething` doesn't fix the problem either, as value types still inherit from `object`, therefore satisfying the constraint.  `IFoo<IChild> bar = foo;` and `DoSomethingElse(foo);` both work because each have an implicit cast from `foo` to `IFoo<IChild>`, which is a reference type.

I would ask the same question that Mike Strobel asked in the comments above: why not change your DoSomething signature from

```
public static void DoSomething<TFoo>(this TFoo foo)
        where TFoo : IFoo<IChild>
```

to

```
public static void DoSomething<TFoo>(this IFoo<IChild> foo)
```

You don't seem to gain anything by making the method generic.

A few of the posts I read on the topic:

[Generic extension method : Type argument cannot be inferred from the usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630153/generic-extension-method-type-argument-cannot-be-inferred-from-the-usage/3630202#3630202)

[Eric Lippert - Constraints are not part of the signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx)

[C# generics type constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041967/c-generics-type-constraint/5446208#5446208)

Comment: Your answer rests on that excerpt of the spec, which, if you read a little more carefully, actually does *not* say anything about reference types. It talks about implicit reference *conversions* (see §6.1.6 of the spec, which `IChild` -> `IBase` satisfies). Also, the [`class` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) *does* constrain to only reference types (not structs). Additionally, `IFoo<IChild>` is not a reference type (it's an interface that a struct could implement).

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out Mike's comment; I misunderstood it the first time. FacticiusVir did ask the same question in the comments of the original post, though. I answered there that I *am* using the generic parameter, so that I can specify additional constraints on `TFoo` besides the `IFoo<IChild>` one.

Comment: I should have included a bit more of the spec in my post.  Under section 4.2, a reference type is listed as a class type, an **interface type**, an array type, or a delegate type, so `IFoo<IChild>` is in fact a reference type.  In the `constraint` link you posted it says as much.

Comment: @Warren: Interesting. This deserves its own question -- an interface is a reference type, but structs (value-types) can implement interfaces. Does that mean structs exposed through their interface are reference types? In any case, this is all tangent to my original question -- it's nothing to do with reference/value types, since there is no compile error when `IFoo` does not take a type parameter (try using e.g. `where TFoo : ICloneable` instead -- it will compile fine).

Comment: @Cameron: when you cast a struct to an interface type, the struct is boxed, so a copy is made and referred to by the interface type.  If you change IFoo and remove the type parameter, then there is no variance, correct? Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: @Cameron: After a bit more playing with this in a demo project I see that you're right about this not being about reference/value types.  There seems to be something about the inferred type in `DoSomething` that doesn't want to play nicely with the specified type in `DoSomethingElse`.  It's curious that if both extension methods are generic, even with DoSomethingElse constrained by the base interface like this `DoSomethingElse<TFoo>(this TFoo foo) where TFoo : IFoo<IBase>`, the code compiles without problem.

Comment: @Warren: Right. This behaviour apparently only happens under *very* specific circumstances.